# How to pass run time values to environment variables in Gradle?

Tags: gradle, groovy

I have written custom exec task in gradle and I want to pass run time argument for environment variable.

```
//Set Go Root and Go Path variables
task setGoPath(type:Exec) {
environment 'GOROOT', "$root" // Had to pass /usr/local/go
environment 'PATH', '$PATH:$GOROOT/bin'
environment 'GOPATH', "$path"//path of my current work directory
}
```

I am executing the task like `gradle setGopath -Proot=/usr/local/go -Ppath=/home/go/sample`

But it throws up error like Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: execCommand == null!

I tried using single quotes in the place of GOROOT value still the same. Is it possible/right to substitute environment values like I do?

Answer (score 0):

You are correctly setting the environment for the executable but you aren't specifying which executable to actually run.

Make sure you specify either the path to the [executable](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec:executable) or the [command line](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec:commandLine) of the executable.

```
//Set Go Root and Go Path variables
task setGoPath(type:Exec) {
    environment 'GOROOT', "$root" // Had to pass /usr/local/go
    environment 'PATH', '$PATH:$GOROOT/bin'
    environment 'GOPATH', "$path"//path of my current work directory
    executable '/path/to/executable/to/run'
}
```

Comment: I have a Go program to download all dependencies and install it in the GOPATH directory. I do not have any specific executable to run. If I dont specify an executable, the environment value would be set to the current process right?

Comment: If you don't have an executable, why are you using the `Exec` task?

Comment: @tim_yates I have many sub folders under the main src folder and I want to install all those executables. So it is not a single path. To make it more clear, the Go commands that I am trying to execute is something like
`commandLine 'go build -v src/code.test.com/util/*.go'
commandLine 'go build -v src/code.test.com/libs/*.go'`

In this case i want to specify only those environment variables and execute these commands. and that will take care of installing my dependencies